# Soap Request Failing

Tags: c#, soap, postman

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'InsertPayments'. End element 'InputXML' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'engine' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Line 8, position 13.

This works and sends "Test" to the method.

```
<soap:Body>
        <InsertPayments xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <InputXML>
            Test
            </InputXML>
        </InsertPayments>
    </soap:Body>
```

I need to send xml and adding the xml results in the following

```
<soap:Body>
        <InsertPayments xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <InputXML>
                <engine>
                    <engineversion>1</engineversion>
                    <serverculture>en-ZA</serverculture>
                    <requestingpersonname>pieter.swanepoel</requestingpersonname>
                    <authcode>9631853F-38CA-45BD-8DFE-E70FC445F8EB</authcode>
                </engine>
            </InputXML>
        </InsertPayments>
    </soap:Body>
```

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'InsertPayments'. End element 'InputXML' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'engine' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Line 8, position 13.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess `<engine>` is a custom XML-tag?

Did you add the `DataContract()` or `Serializable` tag to the custom element?
As the error message indicates the object isn't serializable, these tags could solve that issue.

I'm very new to SOAP and somewhat new to APIs myself so I might be completely off though :D

Comment: Thanks. I landed up writing a wrapper.